# Meaning and origin of "belt and braces"

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains

What does the phrase *belt and braces* mean and where did it come from?

I have a rough idea but would like to see if anyone has a proper definition for this phrase.

Comment: Hi ghostJago. I did a Google search for *phrase origin "belt and braces"* and got a page at [the phrase finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/61250.html). What about this have you found lacking? As the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close) explains - questions that can be answered by a single link to a good resource should not be asked.

Comment: I re-read the faq and couldn't find "questions that can be answered by a single link to a good resource should not be asked" (or similar)  but I will keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: It's in the link I gave, under general reference: **general reference**
This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Comment: I would expect to find that definition in the **What kind of questions can I ask here?** section, not in the **Why are some questions closed?** section, as this question is not closed.

Comment: You have a good point. I was surprised I had to look there, myself.

Comment: :) I've asked about this on meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means to take redundant precautions as a failsafe measure.  It comes from the idea of holding your trousers (AmE:pants) up with both a belt and braces (AmE:suspenders).